# Getting white space right hand side when loading Sencha html page in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I am developing cross-platform mobile application using Sencha-Touch then deploying into web server, when I load the page into webview in Android, getting white space line right hand side of the screen, the same code run in browser in Emulator, it is working fine.

Comment: I have the same bug, I use tabpanel with top and bottom bar

Answer (score 0):

It is the vertical scrollbar of the webview. In a Sencha Touch application you should disable WebView's vertical scrollbar:

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```